Error with connecting to crossbar from JavaScript
I hope someone can help with this:
We have crossbar running as the backend, and on the client side, we have this code in JavaScript:
connection.onclose = function(reason, details) {
    if(details && details.reason === "loggedOut") {
        appEvents.trigger("sessionExpired");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Crossbar connection closed because of ${reason}. Attempting to reconnect in ${RETRY_DELAY_SECONDS} seconds.`);
        if(details) {
            console.log(`Details of closed connection: `, details.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log("No details found");
        }
    }
}

When it is running we got the error:
Crossbar connection closed because of closed. Attempting to reconnect in 5 seconds
Details of closed connection:  got invalid return type "<class 'NoneType'>" from dynamic authenticator

I tried to reference the error with crossbar Python code, I and I found
in crossbar/router/auth/pending.py
   def _assign_principal(self, principal):
        if isinstance(principal, str):
            # FIXME: more strict authrole checking
            pass
        elif isinstance(principal, dict):
            # FIXME: check principal
            pass
        else:
            error = ApplicationError.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
            message = 'got invalid return type "{}" from dynamic authenticator'.format(type(principalsp))

So it might be some sort of authentication failed here, but I have no glue what I have to modify the crossbar settings to make the connection work.
Could someone help me to explain this, thank you very much
